# Blender Rendering

Tags: rendering

Hello I've just started using blender a day ago. When I turn on render mode, the mesh leaves behind this trail. I am not sure fix it and what is causing this problem. Thanks.[image]

Comment: This could be an issue with your graphics driver. Try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different renderer? (You can change at the top, Blender Render, or Blender Cycles, or EEVEE) If none of those work, I suggest updating graphics card drivers!